Can you be paid to be a safety pilot?
If you have a commercial certificate, can you be paid to be a safety pilot for someone else shooting approaches under foggles?
Thanks

Yes, as a commercial pilot with a valid Commercial Pilot License (CPL), you are permitted to be remunerated for acting as a safety pilot.
In the scenario described, I am assuming it involves a single-pilot operation, meaning it does not require a multi-crew aircraft. In this case, you would be the Pilot-in-Command (PIC). The individual performing approaches could be considered the Pilot-in-Command Under Supervision (PICUS), but you retain ultimate responsibility as the PIC.
According to regulations:

c) to act as pilot-in-command, in commercial air transportation, of an
aircraft within the appropriate category and certificated for
single-pilot operation.
(ICAO Annex 1 - 2.4.2 CPL Privileges)

Though a training flight would not strictly fall under being "commercial air transportation" by ICAO definition, the same regulation would probably apply within your NAA for being allowed to receive remuneration for such a training flight as still being a "commercial operation" (see FAA Part 91, 121, 135 / EASA Part-SPO). This is ultimately "tidied-up" if you are operating within an Approved Training Organisation (ATO).

If the operation involves an aircraft certificated for operation by more than one pilot (multi crew operations), you could still be remunerated. However you would have to be a safety pilot on the jump seat, as an Airline Transport Pilot License (ATPL) holder would need to serve as the PIC (ICAO Annex 1 - 2.4.2). You can't be PIC of a multi-crew operation with just a CPL.
Example of this type of flying would be during "base training" - flying the visual circuit with no passengers, or being a jumpsuit safety pilot on the first few sectors of airline experience before being "safety pilot released."
